# I need to format the content of the PDF attachment on my trigger

Tags: blob.topdf

I have trigger that creates and attaches a PDF and then send it out as an email. I would need to change the font and margin style on my div **(e.g A.Application Letter Form)** seems to be not working. May I know what should I do so I can format the font and margin of the contents of my PDF file?

trigger FDDEmailReceiptTrigger on eFDDReceipt__c (after insert) {

```
//Run the trigger only for customer community user
if (UserInfo.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase('PowerCustomerSuccess') || UserInfo.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase('CSPLitePortal')) { //fix service now issue INC2637830
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    //Query the related lead for the community user        
    List<Lead> potentialLeads = [SELECT Id,Name,Email,Submitted_From__c FROM Lead WHERE Submitted_From__c =: UserInfo.getUserEmail()];

    //Loop through the triggered records and link them to the respective leads.
    List<eFDDReceipt__c> updateeFDDReceipt = new List<eFDDReceipt__c>();
    for(eFDDReceipt__c e : [SELECT CreatedBy.Name,eFDDLead__c,CreatedDate FROM eFDDReceipt__c  WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]){
        if (potentialLeads != NULL && potentialLeads.size() > 0) {
            e.eFDDLead__c = potentialLeads.get(0).Id;
            e.ReceiptCreatedBy__c = e.CreatedBy.Name;
            e.ReceiptCreatedDate__c = e.CreatedDate;
            updateeFDDReceipt.add(e);
        }
    } 
    update updateeFDDReceipt;

    //Collect all triggered new eFDDReceipt records
    List<eFDDReceipt__c> rec = [SELECT Id, Name, eFDDBrand__r.Name, eFDDBrand__r.eFDDReceipt_Name__c, eFDDBrand__r.eFDDIssuanceDate__c, eFDDDirector__r.Name,eFDDDirector__r.Email__c,CreatedDate,eFDDLead__r.Email,HotelCityAndState__c, Company__c,TitleWithCompany__c, Address__c, City__c, State__c, Zip__c FROM eFDDReceipt__c  WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];
    System.debug('++++'+rec);

    //Collect the From Address ID from the Organization wide address 
    OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'americas.development@ihg.com'];

    Document d = [Select Id,Name from Document Where Name = 'IHG FDD Email Footer'];
    String docId = d.Id;

    //Loop through the eeFDDReceipt__c records and send mail.
    for(eFDDReceipt__c e : rec){   

        //Create attachment for the mail.
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
        attach.setFileName('FDDReceipt.pdf');
        String attchment;
        attchment = '<html><div><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">EXHIBIT K</span><br style="font-weight: bold;"/></div><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">RECEIPT</span><br style="font-weight: bold;"/></div><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">'+e.eFDDBrand__r.eFDDReceipt_Name__c+'</span><br/></div><br/>This disclosure document summarizes certain provisions of the franchise agreement and other information in plain language.&nbsp; Read this disclosure document and all agreements carefully.<br/><br/>If Holiday Hospitality Franchising, LLC offers you a franchise, it must provide this disclosure document to you 14 calendar-days before you sign a binding agreement with, or make a payment to, the franchisor or an affiliate in connection with the proposed franchise sale.<br/><br/>Rhode Island requires that we give you this disclosure document at the earlier of the first personal meeting or 10 business days before the execution of the franchise or other agreement or the payment of any consideration that relates to the franchise relationship.<br/><br/>Michigan requires that we give you this disclosure document at least 10 business days before the execution of any binding franchise or other agreement or the payment of any consideration, whichever occurs first.<br/><br/>If Holiday Hospitality Franchising, LLC does not deliver this disclosure document on time or if it contains a false or misleading statement, or a material omission, a violation of federal law and state law may have occurred and should be reported to the Federal Trade Commission, Washington, DC 20580 and the state agency listed on Exhibit E.<br/><br/>The franchisor is Holiday Hospitality Franchising, LLC, located at Three Ravinia Drive, Suite 100, Atlanta, Georgia&nbsp;30346.&nbsp; Its telephone number is (770) 604-2000.<br/><br/>Issuance date: ' + e.eFDDBrand__r.eFDDIssuanceDate__c + '.<br/><br/>The franchise seller for this offering is <strong>' + e.eFDDDirector__r.Name + '</strong>, Holiday Hospitality Franchising, LLC, ThreeRavinia Drive, Suite 100, Atlanta, Georgia&nbsp; 30346, (770)604-2000.<br/><br/>Holiday Hospitality Franchising, LLC authorizes the respective state agencies identified on Exhibit D to receive service of process for it in the particular state.<br/><br/>I received a disclosure document dated ' + e.eFDDBrand__r.eFDDIssuanceDate__c +' that included the following Exhibits:<br/><br/><div style="margin-left: 40px;">A.Application Letter Form<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">B.License Agreement, Brand Specific Provisions to License Agreement and State Addenda<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">C.Master Technology Agreement And Joinder Agreement<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">D.Agents for Service of Process<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">E.State Franchise Administrators<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">F1.List of Current Franchisees<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">F2.List of Former Franchisees<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">G1.Financial Statements of Holiday Hospitality Franchising, LLC<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">G2.Financial Statements of Six Continents Hotels, Inc.<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">H.IHG Merlin Terms and Conditions<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">I.Ancillary Agreements<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 80px;">I1.IHG Voice Reservation Service Agreement<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 80px;">I2.Revenue Management for Hire Agreement<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 80px;">I3.Coca-Cola Participation Agreement<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">J.State Addenda to Disclosure Document<br/></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;">K.Receipt<br/></div><br/><br/><br/>Dated: ' + System.Now().Format('MMMM dd, YYYY') + '<br/><br/><br/><strong>PROSPECTIVE FRANCHISEE:</strong><br/><br/><br/><strong>Name (This will serve as your Electronic Signature):</strong><br/>' + e.Name + '<br/><br/><br/><strong>City and State of Hotel To Be Licensed:</strong><br/>' +e.HotelCityAndState__c + '<br/><br/><br/><strong>Company Name:</strong><br/>' +e.Company__c + '<br/><br/><br/><strong>Title with Company:</strong><br/>' +e.TitleWithCompany__c + '<br/><br/><br/><strong>Address :</strong><br/>' +e.Address__c + '<br/><br/><br/><strong>City:</strong><br/>' +e.City__c + '<br/><br/><br/><strong>State:</strong><br/>' +e.State__c + '<br/><br/><br/><strong>Zip:</strong><br/>' +e.Zip__c + '</div></html>';        
        //Create body for the mail.
        String body;

        String domainName = System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();
        String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        String docUrl = domainName+'/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id='+docId+'&oid='+orgId;

        body =  'Dear ' + e.Name + ',' + attchment + '<br/><br/>Regards,<br/>IHG<br/><br/><a href="http://www.ihgplc.com">IHG®</a> | <a href="http://www.ihg.com">Book IHG</a> | <a href="http://www.ihg.jobs">Join IHG</a> | <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/intercontinental-hotels-group">LinkedIn</a> | <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ihg">Facebook</a> | <a href="http://www.twitter.com/ihg">Twitter</a><br/><br/><img src="'+docUrl+'" width="480px" height="90px"><br/>';

        //Convert the attchment to pdf.
        attach.Body = Blob.toPDF(attchment);

        //Add the list of mail address to send the mail to
        List<String> mailAdd = new List<String>();
        if (e.eFDDDirector__r.Email__c != Null) {
            mailAdd.add(e.eFDDDirector__r.Email__c);
        }
        if (UserInfo.getUserEmail() != Null) {
            mailAdd.add(UserInfo.getUserEmail());
            System.debug('++++'+UserInfo.getUserEmail());
        }
        mailAdd.add('americas.development@ihg.com');
        //mailAdd.add('somtirtha1987@gmail.com');
        //Create and set mail receipent, subject, body and attachment.
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        if ( owea != NULL && owea.size() > 0 ) {
            mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
        }
        mail.setToAddresses(mailAdd);            
        mail.setSubject('FDD Receipt');
        mail.setHtmlBody(body );
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach });     
        mails.add(mail);  
    }

    //Check for emptiness of the mail list and send mail
    if(!mails.isEmpty()) {
        Messaging.SendEmail(mails);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would think a more workable approach to be a `Visualforce Page` rendering the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

As a sample I used an existing page rendered as PDF and wrote a little method to show how this could be done for you. It is very simple. Just to illustrate i also took some screenshots for you.

Page Sample:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="PDF" >
   <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Id}" />
   <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}" />  
</apex:page>
```

Method:

```
public void SendPDFPageAttachment( Id acctId ){

    PageReference pdfPage = Page.Test;
    pdfPage.getParameters().put( 'id', acctId );
    pdfPage.setRedirect( true );

    Blob bod = pdfPage.getContent();

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment att = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    att.setBody( bod );
    att.setFileName( 'Some-PDF-Attachment.pdf' );

    String[] toAddresses = new String[]{ 'bcsalt386@gmail.com' };
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    msg.setPlainTextBody( 'Email Body...' );
    msg.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
    msg.setFileAttachments( new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{ att } );
    msg.setSubject( 'Some subject stuff...' );

    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] result = Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{ msg } );
}
```

The result here as you can see below is an email with a PDF attachment.

[image: PDF Email Attached]

[image: PDF File result]

I hope that this helps to get you on your way to solving your issue. Using a PDF page for sure is the key here.

Comment: I thought that the getContent will not work on triggers?

Comment: a simple solutiion for this would be to fire off a queueable from your trigger and do this asynchronously - this type of thing should be done async anyway and would not compromise your performance - you can do the receipt processing in the trigger - all that you need to do there and then send that data you need to a queueable and send this out - simple solution.